# place an image with text to the right

Tags: html

I would like to have a scrolling list of images with a paragraph of text next to each.

The images will all be of an identical size, but the text length will vary.

The whole lot needs to be able to scroll up and down on an iPad.

The size of the page will be fixed so I don't need to worry about orientation.

I'm very new to html so please excuse the question if it is very simple!

Comment: Please add a code example to your question showing what you've tried.

Comment: I believe people are downvoting because your question is asking for too many requirements and is expecting someone to code for you. Please focus your question to a more specific problem, instead of a general task. You can provide what you've done so far as a start, and explain what your code does vs what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right;` in the style/css of the paragraph.

```
<p style='float:right;'>Paraghraphehhehrher</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Sizing your images

This can be done using CSS very easily. So when you insert your image, you can give it a class. e.g

```
    <img class="image" src="some/image/url.jpg" />
```

Then within your CSS code, you can give this image properties:

```
    .image {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
    }
```

This then gives all of the images with a class of "image", a size of 100 by 100 pixels. Alternatively, you can use a photo manipulation tool like photoshop, and re-size the images manually. This could be useful if the images aren't all going to be square, otherwise they will contort when forcing them to be a square when you define the dimensions.

#### Table Approach

Okay, one easy method (to get your head around the idea), would be to use a table, with 2 columns, this approach might look similar to this:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>IMAGE CELL</td>
        <td>TEXT CELL</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

You could then carry this on down the page, inserting the images in one column, and the text in the other. **HOWEVER**, this is considered a poor approach regarding clean web-design. Another method to look at is the method alluded to in Jad's answer.

## The Bootstrap/Foundation Method

Another clean way of approaching this is with the use of a CSS framework like Bootstrap or Foundation. These allow you to work with a grid system on screen, with the screen automatically splitting into 12 columns. You can then use these however you wish.

Read up on [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).